# Convert video to FLV using FFMPEG

Tags: php, flash, ffmpeg, aac

I come across this code in one php script that i bought  last time to convert video. The script is running on Ubuntu 12.04

```
-i $file_source -b 9600k -aspect 16:9 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 128k -ar 22050 $file_dest"
```

That is the full meaning of elements/attributes and what could be the alternative?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Exactly what do you wants?

Comment: I want to convert User submitted video into flv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to convert videos using ffmpeg

**Required Codec:**

1. libmp3lame - acodec
2. libfaac - acodec
3. libvorbis - acodec
4. libx264 - vcodec
5. libtheora - vcodec
6. libvpx - vcodec
7. FFMPEG build Version - ffmpeg version N-54207-ge59fb3f

Commands As Below -

1. Convert to flv -

   ```
   $file_source = "/tmp/test.mp4";
   $file_dest = "/tmp/test.flv";
   ffmpeg -i $file_source -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -preset slower -b 512k -bt 512k -threads 0 -s 640x360 -aspect 16:9 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 32  -f flv -y $file_dest
   ```
2. Convert to mp4 to support HTML5 -

   ```
   $file_source = "/tmp/test.flv";
   $file_dest = "/tmp/test.mp4";
   ffmpeg -y -i $file_source -vcodec libx264 -q:v 1 -preset slower -profile:v baseline -level 30 -crf 30 -vf scale="480:360" -aspect 16:9 -s 640x360 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ac 2 -coder ac -me_range 16 -subq 5 -sc_threshold 40 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -g 250 -r 20 -f mp4 $file_dest
   ```
3. Convert to webm to support HTML5 -

   ```
   $file_source = "/tmp/test.mp4";
   $file_dest = "/tmp/test.webm";
   ffmpeg -y -i $file_source -vcodec libvpx -b:v 480k -bt 480k -preset slower -level 30 -crf 30 -vf scale="480:360" -aspect 16:9 -s 640x360 -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k -ac 2 -coder ac -me_range 16 -subq 5 -sc_threshold 40 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -g 250 -r 20 -f webm $file_dest
   ```
4. Convert to ogv to support HTML5-

   ```
   $file_source = "/tmp/test.mp4";
   $file_dest = "/tmp/test.ogv";
   ffmpeg -y -i $file_source -vcodec libtheora -b:v 480k -bt 480k -preset slower -level 30 -crf 30 -vf scale="480:360" -aspect 16:9 -s 640x360 -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k -ac 2 -coder ac -me_range 16 -subq 5 -sc_threshold 40 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -g 250 -r 20 -f ogg $file_dest;
   ```

For more information about ogg,mp4,web check link [html5-videos-things-you-need-to-know](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-videos-things-you-need-to-know/) and [easyhtml5video](http://easyhtml5video.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a command line instruction for **[FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)** 
You can read the documentation for alternative options at:  **[FFMPEG Docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)**

Anyways just to explain..

`-i $file_source -b 9600k -aspect 16:9 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 128k -ar 22050 $file_dest`

Where..
`-i $file_source` is your input file (any media type)

`-b 9600k` is video bitrate

`-aspect 16:9` is widescreen

`-acodec aac -strict experimental` is using AAC codec (is experimental codec so use **strict** to force usage anyway)

`-ab 128k` is audio bitrate 128kb/s

`-ar 22050` is audio samplerate of 22.05 khz

`$file_dest` the output filename (with extension so FFMPEG knows your preferred output format